# MYSQL SELECT using Concat is not returning the desired results?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table that has the userid of player 1 and the userid of player2. This is in regards to the sport of tennis. If user are playing singles then player 1 has a userid and player 2 is 0. If the users are playing doubles then player1 has a userid and player2 has a userid.

```
wp_divisions2
----------------------------------------------------------
|player_div_id|div_group_id|div_player1_id|div_player2_id|
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2104        | 1          |  234         | 0            |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2110        | 1          |  234         | 456          |
----------------------------------------------------------

wp_users
----------------------
| ID   | display_name|
----------------------
| 234  | John Tennis |
----------------------
| 456  | Beth Smith  |
----------------------
```

I am using concat to join the two user's names to form one string. If singles "John Tennis", if doubles "John Tennis - Beth Smith".

This is MYSQL Query works for Doubles, but not singles. If I use this for singles I get all NULLs in the Concat field.

```
Select p1.id, concat(p1.display_name , " - ", p2.display_name), d2.div_wins, d2.div_loss, d2.div_gwins, d2.div_glost, d2.div_rating, lg.league_desc 
FROM wp_users p1
JOIN wp_divisions2 d2 ON p1.id = d2.div_player1_id
LEFT JOIN wp_users p2 ON p2.id = d2.div_player2_id
JOIN wp_leagues lg ON d2.div_league_ID = lg.league_id
Where d2.player_div_id = 2110 AND d2.div_group_id = 1
ORDER BY d2.div_wins DESC, d2.div_loss ASC, d2.div_rating DESC

Singles results:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| player_div_id  | concat(p1.display_name , " - ", p2.display_name)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2104           | NULL                                            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Doubles results:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| player_div_id  | concat(p1.display_name , " - ", p2.display_name)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2110           | John Tennis - Beth Smith                        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The desired result I would like is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| player_div_id  |                                                 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2104           | John Tennis                                     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2110           | John Tennis - Beth Smith                        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think you have you concat and coalese parameters a bit mixed up, have a look in the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use IFNULL instead of coalesce like this:

```
Select p1.id, concat(p1.display_name , ifnull(concat(" - ",p2.display_name),"")), d2.div_wins, d2.div_loss, d2.div_gwins, d2.div_glost, d2.div_rating, lg.league_desc 
FROM wp_users p1
JOIN wp_divisions2 d2 ON p1.id = d2.div_player1_id
LEFT JOIN wp_users p2 ON p2.id = d2.div_player2_id
JOIN wp_leagues lg ON d2.div_league_ID = lg.league_id
Where d2.player_div_id = 2104 AND d2.div_group_id = 1
ORDER BY d2.div_wins DESC, d2.div_loss ASC, d2.div_rating DESC
```